# Use of 'the' before gerund and change in meaning

Tags: gerunds

"Playing cards is not allowed here."

"The playing of cards is not allowed here."

Why do we need to use 'of' when 'the' is placed before gerund?

Comment: I'm not sure how to describe this issue in grammar/syntax terms, but I think it's to do with the fact that ***playing*** is a straightforward ***verb*** form in the first example (same as ***Using** bad language is forbidden*), whereas in the second example it's a (gerund) ***noun*** (compare ***The use of** bad language is forbidden*). But note that ***the*** isn't actually *necessary* in either my example or yours (and for reasons I can't put my finger on, I find *your* example #2 for less idiomatic than mine, with or without the article).

Comment: It's comparable to "The game of cards is not allowed here".

Comment: I agree with FumbleFingers and BillJ. They've hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it goes like:

When you make a sentence with article “the” , it means you are specifying the kind of playing that you do. So you would need “of” to attach the action of playing with the kind.

> - **The** X **of** Y
> - **the** playing **of** cards isn’t allowed here.

- Q- What kind of playing is not allowed here?
- A-The playing of cards.